# How to locate a button with a dynamicID

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I am automating an Android app using Appium where we need to click a button with a dynamic ID. Either the button has ID "PROFILEBUTTON" or ID "PROFILEMAILBUTTON". Apart from co-ordinates, what else can be used to automate clicking this button?

Comment: Could you add its html code?

Comment: Try to locate via the different locator - CSS, Name or etc.

Comment: There is no unique locator for this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify an element with *dynamic ID* either **PROFILEBUTTON** or **PROFILEMAILBUTTON** you can use cssSelector with the following wildcards :

- ^ : To indicate an attribute value starts with
- $ : To indicate an attribute value ends with

So the most granular locator would include the strategy to lookout for the initial letters i.e. *PROFILE* and the ending letters i.e. *BUTTON* and should be :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id^='PROFILE'][id$='BUTTON']"));
```

---

### Update

As per your comment update, you can use either of the equivalent *xpath* as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@resource-id,'profileMail') and contains(@resource-id,'Button')]"));
//or
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@resource-id,'profileMailButton') or contains(@resource-id,'profileMailPremiumButton')]"));
```

Comment: How can this written with xpath please

Comment: @sandy Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: I get an error. Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS)

Comment: @sandy Can you update me the `tag` name which will contain the element with the mentioned IDs

Comment: resource-id:" net.ilius.android.meetic:id/profileMailButton" or this "net.ilius.android.meetic:id/profileMaiPremiumlButton"                                 
I used : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@resource-id,'net.ilius.android.meetic:id/profileMail')]"));

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 2):

You can use partial id

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id*='PROFIL'][id*='BUTTON']"));
```

Or with `xpath`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//*[contains(@id, 'PROFIL') and contains(@id, 'BUTTON')]"));

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//*[contains(@id, 'PROFIL')][contains(@id, 'BUTTON')]"));
```

Comment: In this case you could (should?) be more specific and use starts with and ends with... `[id^='PROFILE'][id$='BUTTON']` to reduce/eliminate bad matches.

Comment: Does this same applies for xpath? Because css doesnt work for my app.

Comment: @sandy Edited my answer

Comment: I get an error. Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS)

Comment: @sandy Edited the `xpath`

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@resource-id,'profileMailButton') or contains(@resource-id,'profileMailPremiumButton')]"));

This worked for me.