# Simple way to find html-element which has been rendered by React

Tags: html, reactjs, selenium, webpack, attributes

For fast searching elements by Selenium, I think it must be a simple way to set some attributes to html-elements, for example: transform React Component Key to data-attribute (if it is possible).

Of course I can writing id or data-attributes to my span, div and whatever in my components, but I can't do it with components of 3d-party libraries - this components may haven't props like "id", and I will have to wrap this components and then find they by tag or class...

Or maybe is plugin for webpack to set data-attributes to elements with component's names.

However, how you find elements in your react app render?

I think it's not a good idea find elements by class or tags

**key transform like this**:

```
    <MyComponent key="SuperComponent" />
    ...
    <div data-attr="SuperComponent">...</div>
```

**or autoset attributes of component name like this**:

```
    <MySuperComponent />
    ...
    <div data-attr="MySuperComponent">...</div>
```

Comment: If data-attr="SuperComponent" is unique to that element on the page, it's as good as an ID.

Comment: @JeffC of course unique element must have ID instead some data-attr, but question is not about it

Comment: No, you don't have to have an ID to uniquely locate an element on a page. My question was if the attribute/value `data-attr="SuperComponent"` was unique on the page. If so, you can use that instead of putting IDs on everything. For example, run `$$("div[data-attr='SuperComponent']")` in the dev console and see if it returns only 1 element. If it does, then you have a unique locator.

Answer (score -1):

From *"Test Automation* through *Selenium"* perspective it hardly matters if the HTML consists of *id* or *data-attributes*. While working with *Selenium* tests are written with the help of any effective `<tag>` and the associated *attributes*. However there is a preferred list of [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as follows:

[image: Locator Strategies]

### How to find elements in react app render?

The *AUT (Application Under Test)* being [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) based of-coarse the element will be having dynamic attributes. *Locator Strategies* can also be dynamic. You can find an example usage of *Dynamic Locator Strategies* in the discussion [How to locate a button with a dynamicID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115507/how-to-locate-a-button-with-a-dynamicid/50123102#50123102)

Finally, while *Test Automation* the fast moving *WebDriver* instance will be needed to be synchronized with the lagging browser. You can find a relevant discussion in [Do we have any generic funtion to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-funtion-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleniu/50329056#50329056)

Comment: okay, I can use id for every tested element, but how to set id's (handle writing it's not a solution, we need automate everything :) )

Comment: really, I don't believe that in react world isn't a simple way for convert Component name or Componeny Key to element ID