# How to locate a particulat checkbox from a series of checkboxes using Selenium and Python 3.7.4

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to develop a bot that automatically handles the deletion of various posts from a website. I have stumbled across a major problem which does not allow me to proceed any further.

The page I've achieved to open presents various checkboxes with the following input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="305664759" onclick="toggleDeleteButtons()">
```

What I have to do is check simultaneously each checkbox and then click on delete button. Then a popup will appear, where I have to click another "Delete" button with the following input:

```
<input id="btnDelAds" class="button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.manageads.cmd.value='del';if (submit_batch_delete()){document.manageads.submit();}else{closeDialogDelete();}">
```

And then another popup will appear for confirming, but that's another problem. 
In fact, the troubles come when I try to find the checkboxes.

This is the code for handling the first part of the site, and findind the checkboxes:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#HANDLING ACCESS
email = "somemail"
password = "somepass"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.somesite.it/account/manageads")
login_field = driver.find_element_by_id("login_email")
login_field.clear()
login_field.send_keys(email)
login_field = driver.find_element_by_id("login_passwd")
login_field.clear()
login_field.send_keys(password)
login_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#HANDLING DELETE OF POSTS
while True:
    try:
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and contains(@name, 'id')")
        print("Found")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("End")
        break
    elem.click()
```

(I've censored site url and credentials)

`print("Found")` clause is obviously not executed. The idea was to check consecutively every checkbox, probably I've done this in the wrong way.

What I get instead is "END" in console. 
Any help will be strongly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To trigger the presence of the *popup* with text as **Delete** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name^='ids'][onclick^='toggleDeleteButtons'][type='checkbox']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@name, 'ids') and starts-with(@onclick, 'toggleDeleteButtons')][@type='checkbox']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to locate a button with a dynamicID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115507/how-to-locate-a-button-with-a-dynamicid/50123102#50123102)

Comment: I will try it and let you know. However, the popup must be triggered only after checking all checkboxes related to the posts.

Comment: @KingPowa _check simultaneously each checkbox_ Relevant HTML please?

Comment: first of all thank for you patience. I posted the HTML releated to each checkbox in the first post. They all appear with this template: `<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="some_int_value" onclick="toggleDeleteButtons()">`. If you wish, I can post an image of the checkboxes. I took this chuck of code from source code of the page,